# miredo not showing interface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ipv6

I am trying to setup miredo tunnel on my ubuntu. I installed miredo on my machine. When I check status of miredo service

```
● miredo.service - Teredo IPv6 tunneling
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/miredo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-04-20 18:17:22 IST; 2min 26s ago
  Process: 14589 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/miredo-checkconf -f /etc/miredo/miredo.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14592 (miredo)
   CGroup: /system.slice/miredo.service
           ├─14592 /usr/sbin/miredo -f
           ├─14593 /usr/sbin/miredo -f
           └─14594 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/miredo/miredo-privproc A

Apr 20 18:17:22 manu-ThinkCentre-E73 systemd[1]: Starting Teredo IPv6 tunneling...
Apr 20 18:17:22 manu-ThinkCentre-E73 systemd[1]: Started Teredo IPv6 tunneling.
Apr 20 18:17:22 manu-ThinkCentre-E73 miredo[14592]: Starting...
Apr 20 18:17:22 manu-ThinkCentre-E73 miredo[14592]: miredo[14592]: Starting...
Apr 20 18:17:34 manu-ThinkCentre-E73 miredo[14593]: No reply from Teredo server
Apr 20 18:17:34 manu-ThinkCentre-E73 miredo[14592]: miredo[14593]: No reply from Teredo server
```

It's running. But when I check my interface it's not showing teredo interface

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:cb:8a:0c:ff:06  
          inet addr:192.168.2.230  Bcast:192.168.7.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::dacb:8aff:fe0c:ff06/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3073382 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:315655 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:819770191 (819.7 MB)  TX bytes:27992299 (27.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:25717 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25717 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2616881 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:2616881 (2.6 MB)
```

So whats the issue?

Comment: It says "No reply from Teredo server", so apparently the service cannot contact any Teredo server. Are you sure Teredo packets are forwarded by your infrastructure (firewalls, router, NAT gateway)?

Comment: how we can check that.I am not a network guy

Answer (score -1):

try to start mirodo service after rebooting your machine:

> sudo miredo -f